# Why do when adding a column all rows get the value of null?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to add a new column to an existing table. Expected to be UNKNOWN instead all rows get the value of null. Please help. Here's my code.

Grade.kt

```
package com.example.demo.model

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
class Grade {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null
    var grade: Int? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var enabled: Boolean = false
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var studentStatus: StudentStatus = StudentStatus.UNKNOWN

}
```

First I created this table without studentStatus. Now I want to add studentStatus var to the table and I found out that I have to declare it in Gradle.kt to StudentStatus.UNKNOW but instead it gets null.

StudentStatus.kt

```
package com.example.demo.model

enum class StudentStatus{
    PASS,
    FAIL,
    UNKNOWN
}
```

GradleRepository.kt

```
package com.example.demo.repository

import com.example.demo.model.Grade
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface GradeRepository : CrudRepository<Grade, Long>
```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.71'
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')
    runtimeOnly('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: You need to tell hibernate that `studentStatus` has a default value, otherwise it will use NULL as the default value

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can add a new column to an existing table when you define an additional attribute on your class. But Hibernate will not automatically migrate existing values/rows.

For this case you should use a database migration tool like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/). Spring Boot [supports both](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool). These tools help you to write a migration that is exceted once on the next application boot the update existing entries in your database with the missing values.

I assume that you have the issue only with existing values as the defined default looks correct for new inserted values.

Comment: No, I'm having issue with new values. And as I'm adding new column I want to all new column values be equal to UNKNOWN instead of null. But I get null.